# Sending more data with Laravel passport oauth/token

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

So, I'm using Laravel+Passport and so far is working fine.

But, I would like to made a small change to the passport code(well, not in the vendor folder, I hope), once that I would request the User to change it's password in case that he is doing the first login.

So, what I would need is two things (I believe):

1 - How can I add one more info to the oauth/token response? Together with the access_token, I would like to add one column from the DB that is needsNewPassword=true/false.

2 - In case that needsNewPassword is true, then, the app will redirect to another screen, where the user will set a new password. I would set the new password, remove the flag for needsNewPassword and send back a new access_token to the user. The user then, would use only that access_token. How can I regenerate a new access_token?

Thanks for you help! João

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right,

I answering my own question, in case someone needs to do the same. Maybe is not the best way, but is working.What I did is:

- Create a new route, like /api/login that points to a method (be sure that is Outside of your middleware "auth", once that it's not sending the token in thi call). E.g: `Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@apiLogin');`
- in the method, you do a request to the oauth/token and, with the result, you add the fields that you want.
  test

  ```
  function apiLogin(Request $request) {
      $tokenRequest = $request->create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $request->all());
      $request->request->add([
         "client_id"     => 'your_client_id',
         "client_secret" => 'your_client_secret',
         "grant_type"    => 'password',
         "code"          => '*',
      ]);

      $response = Route::dispatch($tokenRequest);
      $json = (array) json_decode($response->getContent());
      $json['new_value'] = '123456';
      $response->setContent(json_encode($json));
      return $response
  }
  ```

  This is working for me. In my case, I also have just one app so, my client_id, client_secret, grant_type and code is added in the server side. The client only need to pass username(or email, depends of what you are using) and password and then it will get the access_token and the other info that I want to send as well.
  Hope that this helps someone else too.

Cheers,
joao

Comment: How to get this 'new_value' value by using this access token? If I send a request to '/api/user' with access token, I can get the user by saying `$request->user()`. But what about this new added value? $request->new_value does not work

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think that your question is making sense. The entire apiLogin method will be returning the response to the client, which includes more information, in this case, the new_value, as part of the JSON returned. What you are asking appears to be how to read it in the server, which is not the case here. Here you want the server to return something else to the client.

Comment: this is not secured at all. You are not adding value to token rather to a json response

Answer (score 2):

@joao.sauer 
Your own answer is working like a charm, but if you wan't a bit more freedom, you could extend Passport's own AccessTokenController.

A simple example:

```
use App\Models\User;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Response;

class AccessTokenController extends \Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController
{
    public function issueToken(ServerRequestInterface $request)
    {
        try {
            //get username (default is :email)
            $username = $request->getParsedBody()['username'];

            //get user
            $user = User::where('email', '=', $username)->firstOrFail();

            //issuetoken
            $tokenResponse = parent::issueToken($request);

            //convert response to json string
            $content = $tokenResponse->getBody()->__toString();

            //convert json to array
            $data = json_decode($content, true);

            if(isset($data["error"]))
                throw new OAuthServerException('The user credentials were incorrect.', 6, 'invalid_credentials', 401);

            //add access token to user
            $user = collect($user);
            $user->put('access_token', $data['access_token']);

            return Response::json(array($user));
        }
        catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) { // email notfound
            //return error message
        }
        catch (OAuthServerException $e) { //password not correct..token not granted
            //return error message
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            ////return error message
        }
    }
}
```

credits to Messi89:
[Laravel Passport - Customize The Token Response](https://gist.github.com/messi89/489473c053e3ea8d9e034b0032effb1d)

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution without need new request, controller or extends, just add parameters to request and call issueToken via app, it can useful for starter:

```
// in routes/api.php

Route::post('/token',function(Request $request){

    $request->request->add([
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => '2',
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ]);

    return app()->call('\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken');
});
```

Also can add try...catch block to handle exceptions or add parameters to response before send to client

```
Route::post('/token',function(Request $request){

    $request->request->add([
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => '2',
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    ]);

    try {

        $response =  app()->call('\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken');
        $newResponse =  json_decode($response->content());
        // Add parameters to response here
        $newResponse->user = ['user'=>'user','pass'=>'pass'];
        return Response()->json($newResponse);

    }catch (Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\OAuthServerException $e) {
        if ($e->statusCode() == 400) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Invalid request. Please enter username and password.'], $e->statusCode());
        } else if ($e->statusCode() == 401) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Your credentials are incorrect. Please try again.'], $e->statusCode());
        }
        return response()->json('Something went wrong on the server. Please try later.', $e->statusCode());
    }
});
```